# bundle install is not successful cannot install ffi 1.9.9 osx 10.9

Tags: rubygems, ffi

```
bundle install  
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........  
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..  
Resolving dependencies...  
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:   
Using addressable (2.3.8)   
Using sass (3.4.15)   
Using sassy-maps (0.4.0)   
Using breakpoint (2.5.0)   
Using chunky_png (1.3.4)   
Using coderay (1.1.0)   
Using multi_json (1.11.1)   
Using compass-core (1.0.3)   
Using compass-import-once (1.0.5)   
Using rb-fsevent (0.9.5)   
Installing ffi (1.9.9)   
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Moe/.bundler/tmp/8353/gems/ffi-1.9.9 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Users/Moe/.bundler/tmp/8353/gems/ffi-1.9.9/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.9'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: cannot complete bundle install stops and give me the previous error

Comment: Thanks God, I was able to solve the problem,,,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks God, I was able to solve the problem,,,

Turned out to be that one of the requirements is to have the "Command Line Tools" already installed on the system [using: Mac OSX 10.9]
I was counting on that I already have "Xcode" installed, thats why I thought that "Command Line Tools" is bundled and installed with Xcode and it was but I just needed to configure "Xcode" properly....by doing the following:

1.start "Xcode"....

2.Go to "Preferences"

3.Select "Locations" tab

4.Command Line Tools: = select the version of "Xcode" that is already installed on the system. [Drop down menu]

5.Relaunch "Terminal"

6.Clear "Drush" cache

```
    drush cc drush
```

7.Run:

```
    gem install ffi -v '1.9.9'
```

and it was successful.

```
    bundle install
```

success also.

Please note: that I also did reinstall:

RVM:

```
    \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Bundler 1.10.5:

```
    gem install bundler
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: 2020 - Had to work with an old D7 Omega 4 theme. Directions worked perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 31):

For me this issue was fixed by running:

```
bundle update ffi
```

Looks like the gem authors fixed these install issues in [version 1.13.0](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1130--2020-06-01)

Answer (score 9):

A likely culprit would be that Xcode path is wrong. Make sure there is valid Xcode then run this first.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: You beauty! Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

I have tried search many times, install many unknown dependencies on internet but none of them work, the funny thing is you can solve it by **`(For React Native new project creation) try to install the new React Native Project under any folder which its name doesn't contain any SPACE.`**

Answer (score 1):

This instruction helped me

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib
$ sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
$ sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.4.dylib
```

source: https://gist.github.com/Dreyer/0a0976f5606c0c963ab9a622f03ee26d

Comment: worked for me, then followed by `gem pristine --all`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

It was solved by running

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
gem inst ffi
```

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/608#issuecomment-363698071

Comment: In my case installing ffi didn't work, I just simply downgrade gem in `Gemfile`: `gem 'ffi', '1.14.2'`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried everything that is already mentioned here but non of them worked. Finally running the below command worked for me

`gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the error "An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue" while running the command npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject, try initializing your project in a folder directory without spaces. For example, run npx react-native init on the "Desktop" directory, which usually doesn't have spaces in its path. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check if there is any space in you root folder name or the folder its inside , remove that space and try again